# Google Drive API v3 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

Can anybody give me sample code in python to find the folder Id (especially the last folder created) in google drive? Your help will be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Stackoverflow and the Drive API documentation have enough samples of python code for Google Drive API requests, you just need to define the basic steps and patch the corresponding code parts together

1. Any Google Drive API request need to be based on the  [Drive API Quickstart for Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) which implements OAuth2 authorization flow and creation of an authenticated service.
2. Once you have this, you can [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) your files to retrieve their Ids.
3. In order to narrow down the results, you can define the search [parameter q](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files), e.g. specifying `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`.
4. Use the parameter `orderBy` to request that the most recent modified folders will be shown first.
5. Use the paramter `pageSize` to define how many results you want to obtain (if you want to obtain the newst folder Id only - 1 is a valid value).

[Stackoverflow is not meant to help you write a code from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I recommend you to search e.g. with the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive-api%5D+%5Bpython%5D+list+folders) specifications for similar questions and try to patch together your code yourself.

Then, if necessary, post a new question with your code explaining where you got stuck and asking for specific help.

> **Hint**: Before implementing your request into Python, test it with the "Try this API" functionality of the [Files:
>   list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to make sure that you adapted the parameters correctly to your needs